# Unable to see the "Do Not Track" (DNT) header in the fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, request-headers

I need to make a request to an API, and when I include the "Do Not Track" (DNT) header in the request, I am able to successfully send the request via Postman and view the desired set-cookie responses.
[image: Postman Request]

It is quite interesting that when I try to send the same request in a browser, I cannot see the DNT option in the headers. However, if I replace DNT with any other header, I am able to see it in the request headers. Unfortunately, the header that is useful for my purpose is DNT. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

The code block that I used to make the request:

```
  createOCAPISession() {
    return fetch(this.OCAPISessionsURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.get('access_token'),
        DNT: '0',
        Testheader: 'test'
      }
    });
  }
```

Below, you can see the request I sent via the browser. As you can see, even though the Testheader is visible in the request headers, we cannot see the DNT header in the headers, and the response we receive is different from what we see in Postman.

The HTTP Request headers for the request that is sent from the Browser:

[image: The HTTP Request headers for the request that is sent from the Browser]

The HTTP Response headers for the request that is sent from the Browser:

[image: The HTTP Response headers for the request that is sent from the Browser]

Furthermore, I have tested it on different browsers and in incognito mode, yet there is no change. What could be the underlying issue, in your opinion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: MDN says DNT header is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT

Comment: @GrafiCode You are right but even though it is fully supported in the Opera browser, I can not see the DNT header in the request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT#browser_compatibility